# How do I extract the selected ID from a list box to send to a getJSON call in ASP.Net MVC app?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, getjson

I have a list box built like so...

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCalendarId, Model.PeriodList)
```

and have wired up a call to my controller via jQuery and hard coded value works...

```
var calId = 12;
$.getJSON("/Publishing/GetLockState1", { calendarId: calId }, function (data) {//omitted}
```

so now, how do I get the Id the user has selected to pass into the json call, i.e. how to populate calId ?
I tried

```
 calId = $("#SelectedCalendarId").val()
```

but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
calId = $("#SelectedCalendarId :selected").val()
```